# Make IFrame resizable with pure JavaScript no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, resizable

i have iframe

```
<iframe class="myframe" src="some_page.html" width="800px" height="600px" />
```

how do i make it resizable same way as `<textarea></textarea>` tag is resizable?

I dont want to use jQuery just JavaScript please.

Comment: ye -1 it for the fact that you cant do thing without jquery

Comment: The -1 was probably because the question shows absolutely no work on your part, it's just a "how do I do this" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea of how to do it:

- On mousedown on the resize target:

  - Create a mask and put it over the entire window
  - Save the mouse's coordinates
  - Save the iframe's current dimensions
- On mousemove on the mask:

  - Get the new coordinates
  - Compare them to the start coordinates
  - Add the difference to the iframe's starting dimensions and adjust the iframe's width and height
- On mouseup on the mask:

  - Remove the mask

Give it a try, and if you have any more specific problems let me know.